# UTF-8 Encoding Error Compiling Java on Travis-ci

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, travis-ci

I'm creating a webpage with internacionalization and I have some string variables that contain language specific characters such as [á í ñ ¿] and those produce an error on the compilation.

```
 -compile:

    -[mkdir] Created dir: /home/travis/build/Maracars/POPBL5/build/main
    -[javac] Compiling 30 source files to /home/travis/build/Maracars/POPBL5/build/main
    -[javac] /home/travis/build/Maracars/POPBL5/src/resources/Errors_es_ES.java:15: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
    -[javac]            {"login.uperror", "Usuario o contrase�a incorrecta."},
    -[javac]                                                 ^  `
```

I have tried to fix this setting the following enviroment variables without success.

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

LANG 
es_ES.UTF-8

LC_ALL 
es_ES.UTF-8
```

Project does compile correctly on my local machine.